# duda con relación 1 a 1

Tags: sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas tardes, tengo una duda en referente a este proyecto que estoy montando en laravel. Mi problema radica en las relacionship de laravel. Porque creo que es una relación one to one pero no estoy muy seguro, alguna ayuda para llegar a entenderlo bien.

Comment: Edité tu pregunta quitando la etiqueta de Laravel por la de SQL en todo caso ya que tu duda va por ahí y no tiene al momento que ver con Laravel; además para que tu duda sea mejor recibida te recomiendo editar y agregar de forma mas visible la estructura de las tablas a las cuales haces referencia así como las razones por las cuales asumes una relación 1:1 y no estaría de mas el por que tienes duda de dicha relación.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda?